# Prevent NSScrollView from flashing its scroller

Tags: appkit, nsscrollview

I would like to prevent a subclass of NSScrollView from flashing its scroller.

I tried to override `-[NSScrollView flashScrollers]` with empty implementation, but it does not work.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

If you hide the NSScrollView before setting the scroll position and show it again, it will prevent the scrollbars from flashing.

Here's a code sample:

```
[_scrollView setHidden:YES];
[[_scrollView contentView] scrollToPoint: NSMakePoint(0, scrollPosition)];
[_scrollView reflectScrolledClipView:[_scrollView contentView]];
[_scrollView setHidden:NO];
```